# Capacitor Testing

Tags: capacitor, testing

I have some old ceramic capacitors and I wanted to test it to see whether it meets the specification in the datasheet or not. I know how to test the capacitance of it but I do not know how to test the voltage and compare it with the datasheet. Datasheet shows 50V for the rated voltage and the capacitance is 22 uF.

Comment: Voltage rating testing is usually destructive.

Comment: I believe a test of ESR is a better indication of the ageing of an old capacitor.

Comment: What do you suggest to see if there is any aging on them without destroying it ?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage rating is generally a parameter for the maximum voltage which the component can withstand. This maximum voltage could be

- the absolute maximum
- the the typical maximum, or what the component manufacturers' tests found over repeated tests
- a conservative figure well below a threshold expressed in the previous

By testing for the voltage in a given component, you stand to destroy the component when testing. This is certainly not recommended, especially if you have a limited number of components.

If you need to test the components, maybe consider placing the components in an area of the circuit well below the specified threshold and test the component instead for the typical and maximum operating values.